# How to sort a list with a secondary sort if the values are equal?

Tags: racket

I would like to sort a list by alphabetical order. If the strings are the same, sort it by increasing number.

```
(define players(list (list "Arnold" 66 )
                     (list "Butter" 77 )
                     (list "Nutter" 18 )
                     (list "Butter" 5 )
                     (list "Nutter" 2 )
                     (list "Butter" 1 )))


(sort players (lambda (a b) (string<? (first a)(first b))) )

(check-expect (sort players
 (lambda (a b) (string<? (first a)(first b))) )
              (list (list "Arnold" 66 )
                     (list "Butter" 77 )
                     (list "Butter" 5 )
                     (list "Butter" 1 )
                     (list "Nutter" 18 )
                     (list "Nutter" 2 )))
```

Currently I can sort it alphabetically, however when the strings are the same, I do not know how to sort it in increasing number. How can I sort this without using recursion? I can only use abstract list functions and lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following as your sort function:

```lisp
(λ (a b) 
  (if (string=? (first a) (first b))
      (< (second a) (second b))
      (string<? (first a) (first b))))
```

Essentially, if the strings are the same, check the numbers (second position). Otherwise, if the strings were different, use the same thing you were doing before.

Comment: @Weegie can you explain the full limitations? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Nvm, I got it, thanks! Instead of using if, I solved this using and